# Calculating my code for higher values of `k`?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, memory

How do I calculate the mean of `A` for higher values of `k`

```
Unprotect[C]
\[Psi] = Sqrt[2] - 1;
\[Epsilon] = .001;
\[Omega] = 1000000;
k = 20;
j = 1;
A1 = Flatten[
   Table[(s1^j)/(s2^k), {s2, 1, Floor[\[Omega]^(1/k)]}, {s1, 
     Ceiling[((s2^k) (\[Psi] - \[Epsilon]))^(1/j)], 
     Floor[((s2^k) (\[Psi] + \[Epsilon]))^(1/j)]}]];
A2 = Flatten[
   Table[(s1^j)/(s2^k), {s1, 1, Floor[\[Omega]^(1/j)]}, {s2, 
     Ceiling[((s1^j)/(\[Psi] + \[Epsilon]))^(1/k)], 
     Floor[((s1^j)/(\[Psi] - \[Epsilon]))^(1/k)]}]];
A = DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[Intersection[A1, A2]]];
Average=Total[A]/Length[A]
```

For `k=20`, I get that the memory of the system has exceeded. I'm not sure what additional code I must use?

Comment: Are you sure this is the code you're executing? I find that `A1` and `A2` actually get smaller as `k` increases. At `k = 20` `A1` has zero elements. Since it has no intersection with `A2`, this means that `A` is also empty and has a length of zero. The error I get when I run your code is a divide by zero error, not a memory error.

Comment: @MassDefect I assume is a value of k that gives the maximum average because initially from k=10 it seems the average was increasing

Comment: @MassDefect Yes this the code I want. I wanted be sure that the average of `A` was decreasing after a certain $k$.

Comment: Well, I don't think the code above should have any memory issues. I would suggest restarting your kernel, closing any other programs that are using memory, and running the code again. It should take a very small amount of memory for `k = 20`.

Comment: @MassDefect for `k=20` his code `A2` makes a 2D table with $\omega^{1/j} = 1,000,000$ elements in the outer layer. For each of those elements, it makes a list - most of which are trivial but a few thousand are not. I can see it pushing the limits on an older or smaller machine, no?

Comment: @Arbuja `A` is `{}` for `k=20`

Comment: @bRost03 If I don't flatten A2, `ByteCount[A2]` only gives me about 48 MB. Unless I'm missing something, it would have to be a very old machine indeed. Each element of the list that isn't empty just contains a rational number. The total byte count for `A1` and `A2` reaches 250 MB at `k = 2`, though only for a second before `Flatten` is applied. It does explode at `k = 1`, however. I think you'd have nearly a billion elements in one list and nearly 6 billion in the other. That would certainly require a decent amount of memory, but `k = 20` should be fine, I think.